# How to inspect date field in AngularJS application

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I am working on to inspect the date field in AngularJS web application for selenium automation. I have a date field in my page has the Up and Down arrow and one Drop Down like icon which on click will display the date calendar to select the date.

I have two problems.

1. My problem is when i try to inspect the Drop Down like icon it is not showing any control related to the drop down like icon and instead it inspects the whole common date field. Below is the image of how my date field looks like.

[image: Date]

and the..

2. Once i click on the drop down like icon (not the scroll bar icons) i see the calendar table format displays. But the issue is i could not right click on any cells itself.

[image: DateCalendar]

Could anyone help me on this?

To Add, when i try to right click and inspect the Drop Down like icon, below is the html code am seeing in the result.

```
<div class="formDiv">
                        <input id="receivedDateInput" type="date" min="2015-01-01" max="2016-02-16" data-ng-model="receivedDateInput" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false">
                    </div>
```

Comment: that date input is browser specific. Thats just what your browser gives you with an input type="date". A different browser will give a different widget.

Comment: item is in shadow dom ... can see it if you turn on shadow dom in dev tools

Comment: Try these steps: 1. Open Chrome Dev's Tool  2. Click on the date input in your application 3. On the Chrome Dev's Tool > Sources, click "Pause script execution".